# Could stepping down from 220V/50Hz to 110V/60Hz cause issues with household electronics?

Tags: appliances

I have a USA market Yamaha stereo receiver RX-V563 which is 110V/60Hz.  I have moved to China and have a 220V/110V stepdown transformer but I can not get my receiver to work.  The lights come on but I can not get sound out.  Could the 50Hz frequency be keeping the system from working?

Answer (score 2):

That is very likely the problem.  The stepdown transformers step down the voltage, but do not increase the frequency - that is why a hair dryer, for example, will operate slower on 220V/50Hz when it stepped down to 110/50hz.  The audio processing components of the receiver are likely depending on the correct input frequency.  Its also possible that you might have damaged the receiver from doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This model is available in an international version with voltage selection, and in a specific USA version that only works on 110-120 volts.  The USA version has 2 convenience outlets whereas the international version does not.  These convenience outlets are almost certainly the reason it cannot be run at 220-240 volts.  It is possible that it can be converted to 220-240 use, anyway (remove the USA outlets for safety reasons).  The conversion could be tricky, but would involve rewiring the input to the big toroidal transformer so that the 2 windings are in series instead of parallel (probably what the voltage selector does on the international version).

However, it is possible the USA version has a smaller transformer (possible to do with 60 Hz), in which case the 50 Hz power will cause problems, including a lower voltage output to the electronics.  If it does have a smaller transformer, there is a good chance it only has a single primary winding and cannot be converted to run directly on 220-240.  Then the failure of audio due to this is a real possibility.

Google for the model number.